# Run powershell script on a SharePoint site from a different SharePoint server

Tags: sharepoint-2013, powershell-2.0

I have a Sharepoint server (call it SERVER1) of which I'm the server admin. I run a few powershell scripts on that server. 
Now I'm trying to run a script on SERVER1 which needs to access a list from another Sharepoint server (I'm not the server admin there. I'm only the site collection admin)

Here's part of my script:

```
 $srcListSiteUrl = "http://SERVER1/sites/sitename/" 
 .
 .
 .     
 $dstListSiteUrl = "http://SERVER2/sites/sitename/"    
 $dstListWeb = Get-SPWeb -identity $dstListSiteUrl
```

My script fails on the Get-SPWeb command.

> Get-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the following
>   Id or Url: http://SERVER2/sites/sitename/.

Is there a way I can make this happen? Am I missing something very basic?